# Getting ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression error in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am having "ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression" error in a query using group by and having. Can anybody tell me where the problem is?
This is the query.

```
select DEPTNUM, INSTNAME, DEPTNAME from department
NATURAL join academic
group by DEPTNUM
having count(deptnum) > 10
```

Comment: add `INSTNAME, DEPTNAME` behind `group by`

Comment: you are grouping just one column, while selecting other columns that are not in an aggregation function

Comment: Unlike mySQL, Oracle requires you to have any field in the select which is not aggregated in the group by.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eschew `natural join`.  It is pretty much an abomination, because it uses columns that have the same *name* rather than declared foreign key relationships.

Your real problem is the `group by` and `select`.  I would suggest:

```
select DEPTNUM, INSTNAME, DEPTNAME
from department d join
     academic a
     using (deptnum)
group by DEPTNUM, INSTNAME, DEPTNAME
having count(deptnum) > 10;
```

I would also qualify `instname` and `deptname`, but it is not clear what table they come from.

Answer (score 0):

Either add INSTNAME, DEPTNAME in the GROUP BY, or use aggregate function (such as MIN, MAX) for INSTNAME, DEPTNAME

Comment: or remove the unaggregated columns from the select.

Answer (score 0):

If you need  and ggreted  result on  a column you shoudl not have this column in group by
and your error is related  to the fact you have not column in group by clause taht are not aggregated in select

so  try

```
select INSTNAME, DEPTNAME from department
NATURAL join academic
group by INSTNAME, DEPTNAME
having count(deptnum) > 10
```